# Zod Record and Map for unknown object key/value construction

Tags: javascript, zod

I'm using Zod for schema validation and I have been provided with a schema for the request body I should be expecting, however one of the fields simply just describes `object or null` with no hint at what might be contained within the object... In the example responses this key is always null, which again doesn't help.

I have looked at Zod's [record](https://zod.dev/?id=records) but I'm not sure that I fully understand it. From what I can gather, it seems like I can only specify one value type for the entirety of the object, whereas I'm unsure what I will be getting...

Can anyone help provide me with an example of how I can define a truly dynamic object?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to achieve this: `Record<string, any>`? That can be done by using `z.record(z.any())`. You could also narrow it if you would know the set of expected types by building an union using `z.union([/*list of zod types*/])` or by chaining zod types using their `or` method.

Comment: I was looking to see if there was a `.any()` on the official docs but couldn't find it! I would have saved myself some time and your effort if it was obvious XD Good shout about the union one, I was looking for something like that also, although I've no idea if it'll have sub-objects, so I'll stick with the `.any()` for now :-)